# .htaccess storage link

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, enlace, storage

Subí una web app hecha con *laravel* en un server. Todo funciona menos el *storage link*.

Me sugirieron que use **htaccess** del server, pero no tengo idea como hacerlo. Por lo que vi es una terminal, pero no se bien como usarla. Osea no puedo hacer eso de `php artisan link:storage`... no me imagino como debería hacerlo en esta terminal que ademas me parece que es de linux (yo use toda mi vida windows).

Los tutoriales del host dicen que para hacer un redirect tengo que poner esto `Redirect 301 / http://example.com/`... Acá debería poner el url de mi *app/storage*? Soy re novata, necesito ayuda, no encuentro tutoriales y los que encuentro no los entiendo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola no tienes nada que temer puedes usar el comando de `php artisan link:storage` es un comando propio de laravel no tiene nada que ver con el sistema operativo solo depende de php.

Para que tengas una información mas clara lo que hace este comando es crear un enlace simbolico hacia la carpeta de storage, desde public que es donde se ejecuta la aplicación.

Como segunda opción puedes crear un enlace simbolico de con el comando:
`ln -s [target(../public/storage)] [source('storage/app')]` preferiblemente usa rutas absolutas para evitar errores.

Esperto te sea util.

Comment: ya lo probé y en el server no tienen php artisan, o por lo menos me tira que es un comando invalido. Trate de pegar al repositorio de git y tambien de crearlo ahi, y aunque me figura en el repo, despues no me anda...voy a intentar con las rutas absolutas. El comando deberia pegarlo asi como esta en el terminal? Gracias de antemano ^^

Comment: hey si, solo para comprobar ejecutaste el comando de artisan sobre la carpeta del proyecto? si es asi bueno pasa  a intentarlo con el comando ln -s  para crear el enlace simbolico.